# Writing to a text file line by line

Tags: java

I am writing java code to read a from a text file, use the information read to calculate sum and difference and then write the results to a text file. My problem is that I have managed to write to the text file but the results are written as one continuous line. What I want is to have the results written line by line.

I have managed to write to the text file but the results are written as one continuous line.

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("results.text", true);

    Float sumres = rid.Add(a,b);                            
    String sumr = Float.toString(sumres);
    writer.write(sumr);

    Float diffres = rid.Subtract(a,b);                          
    String diffr = Float.toString(sumres);
    writer.write(diffr);

    writer.close(); 
} catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output shows the following as a single line:

> 4.22.24579570.05037037-2.9881759-0.4110921-0.21129033-4.50.750.66666674.22.24579570.05037037-2.9881759-0.4110921-0.21129033-4.50.750.66666674.22.24579572.24579570.050370370.05037037-2.9881759-2.9881759-0.4110921-0.4110921-0.21129033-0.21129033-4.5-4.50.750.750.66666670.66666674.24.2

What I expect is to have output presented line by line as:
4.2 
2.2457957 
0.05037037 
and so on

OR at least have the results have something to show separation

Comment: Use `java.nio.Files`, it has a method [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) where you can provide an `Iterable` (a `List` for example) that represents the lines to be written. You would have to store the values for each line in that `Iterable` before.

Comment: What about using CSV file for column separation. Take a look. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values. It's super easy for implementation. For line separation you can use BufferedWriter as TheWhiteRabbit offers.

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your FileWriter in a BufferedWriter, that way you can use the writer.newLine() method:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("results.text", true))){
  writer.write("");
  writer.newLine();
}
catch(IOException ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

An additional benefit is that the BufferedWriter is more efficient then using the FileWriter directly. In general, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.

Note, in your example you are not managing the writer resource correctly as it will not be closed if an exception occurs, the close should be in a finally block. If using a recent Java version you can use the try-with-resources construct as shown in my example, this will close the writer automatically so you avoid having to write the finally block yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. Things now working perfectly well

Answer (score 6):

Everytime you want to terminate a line you can use the below :

```
writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Alternatively, assuming you want a new line after you write the diff you can also do it like this :

```
writer.write(diffr + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Instead of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` you could just write `System.lineSeparator()`, otherwise good answer...